# Best way for working with real time data withouth making the app slow on Android

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am working on a real time data app. It would be something similar to a sport results app, so it means that I must refresh data almost every time and I guess having an internal database would not be a good idea.

I have an activity wich has 3 tabs, first tab would show for example every game result, in the second tab I would have a filter for finished games and the last tab would be for example live games.

The JSON I download is pretty big and it is a nested JSON, it means that it could take long for my app to parse it and so on.

I have done my class "Matches" for the JSON, this is my HttpManager class:

```
public class HttpManager {
    public static String getData(String uri) {

        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(uri);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            return sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

JSON parser:

```
    public class MatchesJSONParser {

    private static final String TAG = "MatchesJSONParser";

    public static LinkedHashMap<Integer,List<Match>> parseFeed(String content) {

        try {

            LinkedHashMap<Integer,List<Match>> allMatchesList = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            int tournamentId;
            List<Match> matchesList = null;

            JSONArray  jArray1    = new JSONArray(content);

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray1.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jObjt1 = jArray1.getJSONObject(i);
                tournamentId =jObjt1.getInt("relatedToObjectId");
                JSONArray jArray2 = jObjt1.getJSONArray("matches");

                matchesList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int j = 0; j < jArray2.length(); j++) {

                    JSONObject jObjt2 = jArray2.getJSONObject(j);

                    Match match = new Match();

                    match.setId(jObjt2.getInt("id"));
                    match.setTournamentId(jObjt2.getInt("tournamentId"));
                    match.setStatusCode(jObjt2.getString("statusCode"));

                    JSONArray jArray3 = jObjt2.getJSONArray("teams");

                    JSONObject equipo1 = jArray3.getJSONObject(0);
                    JSONObject equipo2 = jArray3.getJSONObject(1);

                    JSONObject resultadoEquipo1 = null;
                    JSONObject resultadoEquipo2 = null;

                    try {
                        resultadoEquipo1 = equipo1.getJSONObject("results");
                        resultadoEquipo2 = equipo2.getJSONObject("results");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.v(TAG, "parseFeed: result = null");
                    }


                    if (equipo1.getInt("number") == 1) {
                        match.setHomeLogo(equipo1.getString("logoUrl"));
                        match.setHomeName(equipo1.getString("name"));
                        if (resultadoEquipo1 != null)
                            match.setHomeScore(resultadoEquipo1.getInt("runningscore"));
                        else
                            match.setHomeScore(-1);

                        match.setAwayLogo(equipo2.getString("logoUrl"));
                        match.setAwayName(equipo2.getString("name"));
                        if (resultadoEquipo2 != null)
                            match.setAwayScore(resultadoEquipo2.getInt("runningscore"));
                        else
                            match.setAwayScore(-1);

                    } else {
                        match.setHomeLogo(equipo2.getString("logoUrl"));
                        match.setHomeName(equipo2.getString("name"));
                        if (resultadoEquipo2 != null)
                            match.setHomeScore(resultadoEquipo2.getInt("runningscore"));
                        else
                            match.setHomeScore(-1);

                        match.setAwayLogo(equipo1.getString("logoUrl"));
                        match.setAwayName(equipo1.getString("name"));
                        if (resultadoEquipo1 != null)
                            match.setAwayScore(resultadoEquipo1.getInt("runningscore"));
                        else
                            match.setAwayScore(-1);
                    }

                    matchesList.add(match);
                    Log.v(TAG, "parseFeed: match added");
                }

                allMatchesList.put(tournamentId, matchesList);
            }

            return allMatchesList;

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.v(TAG, "parseFeed: exception " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

List Adapter:

```
public class ResultListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Match> mList;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater = null;
    private View mView;
    private Holder mHolder;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    public ResultListAdapter(Context context, List<Match> list){
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mList = list;
        this.mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(context.getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (mList != null)
            return mList.size();
        else
            return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        if (mList != null)
            return mList.get(position);
        else
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        mInflater    = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mView        = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_result, parent,false);

        mHolder = new Holder();
        mHolder.homeLogo    = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_result_homelogo);
        mHolder.homeName    = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_result_homename);
        mHolder.homeScore   = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_result_homescore);
        mHolder.awayLogo    = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_result_awaylogo);
        mHolder.awayName    = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_result_awayname);
        mHolder.awayScore   = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_result_awayscore);

        mHolder.homeName.setText(mList.get(position).getHomeName());
        if (mList.get(position).getHomeScore() != -1)
            mHolder.homeScore.setText(String.valueOf(mList.get(position).getHomeScore()));
        else
            mHolder.homeScore.setText("");
        mHolder.awayName.setText(mList.get(position).getAwayName());
        if (mList.get(position).getAwayScore() != -1)
            mHolder.awayScore.setText(String.valueOf(mList.get(position).getAwayScore()));
        else
            mHolder.awayScore.setText("");

        if (isStoragePermissionGranted()) {
            mImageLoader.DisplayImage(mList.get(position).getHomeLogo(), mHolder.homeLogo);
            mImageLoader.DisplayImage(mList.get(position).getAwayLogo(), mHolder.awayLogo);
        } else {
            mHolder.homeLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_default_shield);
            mHolder.awayLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_default_shield);
        }

        mView.setTag(R.string.tag_match_id, mList.get(position).getId());
        mView.setTag(R.string.tag_tournament,mList.get(position).getTournamentId() );

        return mView;
    }

    public class Holder{
        ImageView homeLogo;
        TextView homeName;
        TextView homeScore;
        ImageView awayLogo;
        TextView awayName;
        TextView awayScore;
    }

    private boolean isStoragePermissionGranted(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {

            if (mContext.checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment 1:

```
public class AllFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    private LinkedHashMap<Integer,List<Match>> mMatchesList;
    private View mRootView;
    private HashMap<Integer,String> mTournamentNames;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;

    public AllFragment() {
    }

    public static AllFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        AllFragment fragment = new AllFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        initComponents(inflater, container);

        return mRootView;
    }

    private void initComponents(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container){
        mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all, container, false);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.frag_all_layout);

        mMatchesList = ((App) getActivity().getApplication()).getListMatches();
        mTournamentNames = GeneralUtils.getTournamentNames(getActivity());

        for (Integer key : mMatchesList.keySet()) {
            TextView tournament = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tournament_name_text_view, null);
            tournament.setText(mTournamentNames.get(key));
            linearLayout.addView(tournament);
            ListView lv = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.matches_list_view, null);
            linearLayout.addView(lv);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            ResultListAdapter adapter = new ResultListAdapter(getActivity(), mMatchesList.get(key));
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            GeneralUtils.setListViewHeightBasedOnItems(lv);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("MATCH_ID", view.getTag(R.string.tag_match_id).toString());
        intent.putExtra("TOURNAMENT_ID", view.getTag(R.string.tag_tournament).toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Fragment 2:

```
public class LiveFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    private LinkedHashMap<Integer,List<Match>> mMatchesList;
    private View mRootView;
    private HashMap<Integer,String> mTournamentNames;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;
    private int mLiveMatchesCount = 0;

    public LiveFragment() {
    }

    public static LiveFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        LiveFragment fragment = new LiveFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        initComponents(inflater, container);
        return mRootView;
    }

    private void initComponents(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container){
        mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_live, container, false);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.frag_live_layout);

        mMatchesList = ((App) getActivity().getApplication()).getListMatches();
        mTournamentNames = GeneralUtils.getTournamentNames(getActivity());

        for (Integer key : mMatchesList.keySet()) {
            List<Match> liveMatchesList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < mMatchesList.get(key).size(); i++){
                if (mMatchesList.get(key).get(i).getStatusCode().equals("live")){
                    liveMatchesList.add(mMatchesList.get(key).get(i));
                    mLiveMatchesCount ++;
                }
            }
            if (liveMatchesList.size() > 0){
                TextView tournament = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tournament_name_text_view, null);
                tournament.setText(mTournamentNames.get(key));
                linearLayout.addView(tournament);
                ListView lv = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.matches_list_view, null);
                linearLayout.addView(lv);
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
                ResultListAdapter adapter = new ResultListAdapter(getActivity(), liveMatchesList);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                GeneralUtils.setListViewHeightBasedOnItems(lv);
            }
        }

        if (mLiveMatchesCount == 0){
            TextView tournament = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tournament_name_text_view, null);
            tournament.setText(getString(R.string.no_live_match_available));
            linearLayout.addView(tournament);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("MATCH_ID", view.getTag(R.string.tag_match_id).toString());
        intent.putExtra("TOURNAMENT_ID", view.getTag(R.string.tag_tournament).toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Fragment 3:

```
public class FinishedFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    private LinkedHashMap<Integer,List<Match>> mMatchesList;
    private View mRootView;
    private HashMap<Integer,String> mTournamentNames;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;
    private int mLiveMatchesCount = 0;

    public FinishedFragment() {
    }

    public static FinishedFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        FinishedFragment fragment = new FinishedFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        initComponents(inflater, container);
        return mRootView;
    }
    private void initComponents(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container){
        mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_finished, container, false);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.frag_finished_layout);

        mMatchesList = ((App) getActivity().getApplication()).getListMatches();
        mTournamentNames = GeneralUtils.getTournamentNames(getActivity());

        for (Integer key : mMatchesList.keySet()) {
            List<Match> liveMatchesList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < mMatchesList.get(key).size(); i++){
                if (mMatchesList.get(key).get(i).getStatusCode().equals("finished")){
                    liveMatchesList.add(mMatchesList.get(key).get(i));
                    mLiveMatchesCount ++;
                }
            }
            if (liveMatchesList.size() > 0){
                TextView tournament = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tournament_name_text_view, null);
                tournament.setText(mTournamentNames.get(key));
                linearLayout.addView(tournament);
                ListView lv = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.matches_list_view, null);
                linearLayout.addView(lv);
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
                ResultListAdapter adapter = new ResultListAdapter(getActivity(), liveMatchesList);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                GeneralUtils.setListViewHeightBasedOnItems(lv);
            }
        }

        if (mLiveMatchesCount == 0){
            TextView tournament = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tournament_name_text_view, null);
            tournament.setText(getString(R.string.no_finished_match_available));
            linearLayout.addView(tournament);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("MATCH_ID", view.getTag(R.string.tag_match_id).toString());
        intent.putExtra("TOURNAMENT_ID", view.getTag(R.string.tag_tournament).toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

The app is working fine, the problem for me is that it takes too long when I go from a fragment to another one, it could even take 3 - 4 seconds. I know this is normal because it is processing a lot of data but I would like to know wich would be the best or the right way to do this withouth affecting the app  speed. There are many apps in the market which works with a lot of data and they are not as slow as mine. Could anybody give me a hint? It would be really appreciated. Thanxs in advance

Comment: You should separate the downloading and processing from the UI of course, but even more importantly you should be filtering the data somewhere upstream (at the source, or on a server between the source and the devices on which your app is running) so that the device can pull down only recent changes, instead of constantly re-downloading everything to scan for changes.

Comment: Yes, I download the data using asynctask and so on, I am not doing anything on main thread. So it means the device part is ok and the changes should be done on the server?